# how to increment in number limit of 3 i.e 000

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, integer, range

i have a number limit i.e. 000 now i want to increment it by 1 so the next limit will be '001' but when i try to add it gives me '1',
also if somehow i figure out to maintain it '001', the second problem is after '009' there should be '010'. Advance Thanks for you efforts.

Comment: So, just have a number variable that you're incrementing, then _left pad_  it to 3 characters...

Comment: Try: `('000' + ++count).slice(-3)`

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats padding.

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}
```

Assuming you'll never need more than 3 digits

**[Edit] - For those who like early technology i.e ES7**

There is a new method called `padStart()`

[padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) - *The padStart() method pads the current string with another string (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start (left) of the current string.*

> Example 1

```
const digits = 3

digits.toString().padStart(3, '0') // prints 003
```

> Example 2

```
const digits = 76

digits.toString().padStart(3, '0') // prints 076
```